# Return QueryString(ID) as an integer

Tags: web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, query-string

I actually have a custom dispform with a `XsltListViewWebPart`. This list has a column called `RootId`. I need to filter data from this list based on the ID set in the page's URL.
I can query the ID in my webpart by using this line :

```
<ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0" />
```

And then filter :

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="RootId"/>
                <Value Type="Number">{ListItemId}</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

But the problem is that `RootId`'s type is number and my parameter is a string.
So how can I convert this parameter to an integer ?
Obviously, I can't change

```
<Value Type="Number">{ListItemId}</Value>
```

to

```
<Value Type="Text">{ListItemId}</Value>
```

Thank you for your answers